# sweet alert input to js variable

Tags: javascript, input, sweetalert

I want to have a sweet alert input to ask the user to enter a value. Then I want to save the value as a JS variable, to be used later.

```
let coinName = swal("Enter cryptocurrency name", {content: "input"})
console.log(coinName)
```

Here is my full code:

```
function getPrices() {

let coinName = swal("Enter cryptocurrency name", {content: "input"})
console.log(coinName.value)


$.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')+ coinName.valueOf + '/' + '&callback=?', function (data) {
    console.log(data.contents);
})


    var coinPrice = data.contents[0].price_usd
    swal('Currently, in USD, 1 ' + coinName + ' is equal to $' + coinPrice)


}
```

This what I want to do:

1. Ask user for input.
2. Take input and convert in into JS variable.

I'm not sure if I've explained this correctly, but any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the docs https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-dom-nodes-as-content you can do this with

```
swal("Write something here:", {
  content: "input",
})
.then((value) => {
  // do something with value variable
});
```

If we update your code

```
function getPrices() {
    swal("Enter cryptocurrency name", {content: "input"}).then(function(coinName) {
        $.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')+ coinName + '/' + '&callback=?', function (data) {
            console.log(data.contents);

            var coinPrice = data.contents[0].price_usd
            swal('Currently, in USD, 1 ' + coinName + ' is equal to $' + coinPrice)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but it gives me the error                                                                          --------                                                                                             Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at swal.then (scripts.js:32), and points to the line: var coinPrice = (data.contents[0].price_usd)

Comment: Of course, as data is not yet loaded and defined. Check the updated example and see how callbacks/promises works

Comment: Thank you @FrEaKmAn! The page loads and runs perfectly now. :)